# Facebook API and discovering popular Public posts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-fql

Do you think it is possible to use Facebook API to easily discover popular (viral) Public posts, such as: https://www.facebook.com/knox188/posts/10159451336160245

Or maybe even narrowing down these posts to a specific country. So you could see what's popular for example in Germany.

I'm thinking it would require parsing Public posts data from user profiles and then determining their popularity by running Graph search. But... that's a lot of data.

What do you think? Or maybe you know some free or paid tools that do that? Something like Newswhip Spike - but for user posts, not Facebook Pages

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, that is not possible for normal 3rd-party apps. You don’t get API access to any user posts, unless the user logs in to your app and grants it permission. There is stuff like the Public Feed API, but access to that is limited to a set of Facebook partners (and you can not apply to become one, you could only buy this as a service from one of those.)

Comment: Thank you @CBroe